# Simplifying $b(abb + abbbb + aba^*bbb)^*$

Tags: regular-expressions

I'm having issues simplifying regular expressions. I can't find a method to approach this problem.

How would I approach simplifying this regular expression:

$$b(abb + abbbb + aba^*bbb)^*$$

Comment: How do you evaluate other expressions, say, "arithmetic with symbolic variables"?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $abbbb+aba^*bbb = aba^*bbb$. Also, note that you can "factorize" common expressions in the parentheses.

Your regular expression is equivalent to $b(a(\varepsilon + ba^*b)bb)^*$ (I don't know if it can be simplified again).